# How to get Date/Time difference with Current time in PowerBi

Tags: datetime, powerbi, dax

I have a table with below column.

```
Incident Start Time
13/01/2021 2:28:29 PM
21/01/2021 1:32:29 PM
11/03/2021 12:22:45 PM
11/03/2021 1:23:02 PM
11/03/2021 1:50:19 PM
11/03/2021 1:57:10 PM
```

I want to take the difference of this time with current local time and display the output in seconds in another column. How can I do tha? I am expecting something like below assuming current date time is 25/03/2021 2:28:29 PM

```
Incident Start Time     Incident open Since(seconds)
13/01/2021 2:28:29 PM     6134400
21/01/2021 1:32:29 PM     5446560
11/03/2021 12:22:45 PM    1217144
11/03/2021 1:23:02 PM     1213527
11/03/2021 1:50:19 PM     1211890
11/03/2021 1:57:10 PM     1211479
```

I assume evertime i open or refresh my report this Incident open Since(seconds) will dynamicall change as per my current local time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new column in the same table called `Incident open Since(seconds)` :

```
= DATETIMEDIFF([Incident Start Time], NOW(), SECOND)
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DATEDIFF` to calculate the difference in a calculated column.

### Calculation

```
Incident open Since(seconds) = 
    DATEDIFF([Incident Start Time],TODAY(),SECOND)
```